# Minimum number of decimal places needed to represent a value in the range [0, 255]

Tags: python, floating-point, precision, floating-accuracy

Assume I have a float in the interval `[0.0, 1.0]` that is represented as a string. We will call this value `floatstr`. Let us also assume that this value represents an integer in the interval `[0, 255]`.

The formula for converting `floatstr` to the integer is (in python):
`int(round(float(floatstr)*255))`

What is the minimum number of decimal points required in `floatstr` to represent this value accurately? How is this minimum number calculated, if there is a formula for doing so?

Comment: Your logic is not clear, actually I think there are a lot of ways to map a float in range (0.0, 1.0) to an integer in range (0, 255). Why you are using such algorithm?

Comment: This range is small enough that you could just determine the necessary value by brute force.

Comment: @Kasramvd: I am only mapping it linearly. The reason I am doing so is because I am auto-generating code with my application, and in an attempt to make the output more readable I would like to reduce the number of decimal points displayed every time I print a float. I am just not sure how many decimal points I can remove.

Comment: The minimum is 3 because numbers between  `0.001` and `0.006` would be the minimum numbers with minimum precision, in order to generate the 1.

Comment: @Kasramvd Could you please explain how you arrived to that conclusion?

Comment: Because `255 = 0.25 * 10**3`. Since the number 1 would generate the 255 for you you need to find the float number that generates the number 1 for you, because you are looking for the minimum decimal. So you need to create a **scientific notation** of your number then the power of 10 would be the minimum number of decimals.

Comment: @Kasramvd: Thank you for the great explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two digits obviously won't cut it. You'd only be able to represent 100 distinct values. How about 3 digits?

Say we have a number `x/255`, and we display that to 3 digits after the decimal point, effectively rounding it to some number `y/1000`. Multiplying `y/1000` by `255` and rounding it will produce `x` if `x/255` is the closest multiple of `1/255` to `y/1000`.

If `x/255 = y/1000`, then it's obviously the closest multiple of `1/255`. Otherwise, `x/255` must be within a distance of `1/2000` of `y/1000` to round to `y/1000`, so the closest multiple of `1/255` on the other side of `y/1000` must be at least a distance `1/255 - 1/2000` away, further than `x/255`. Thus, `x/255` is the closest multiple of `1/255` to `y/1000`, and 3 digits are enough. Similarly, for any denominator `d` with `n` digits, `n` decimal places should be enough (and if `d` is a power of 10, `n-1` decimal places should do it).

(I've neglected the impact of implicit floating-point rounding error in this derivation. For small denominators, floating-point rounding error should not change this analysis.)

Comment: You can completely eliminate floating point rounding error as an issue by using 256 as the divisor. In IEEE 754 binary floating point, all divisions of a number in [0,255] by 256 are exact.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan: You'd still have to be careful when dealing with the decimal representation, though, because if you read that back in as floating point, you incur a rounding error, and you're back to having to think about whether that matters.